Thymeleaf not displaying error message and do not save the enterend email after failed login in Spring Security
I use Java 17, Spring Boot 3.2.4 and Gradle
On login fail with wrong password and username (email) Thymeleaf not displaying error message and not redirect the result (email) after failed login in Spring Security
My auth-login html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">

<head th:replace="~{fragments/head :: head}"></head>
<body>
<div th:replace="~{fragments/navbar :: navbar}"></div>

<!-- Login 2 - Bootstrap Brain Component -->
<div class="bg-light py-3 py-md-5" id="auth-login">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-7 col-xxl-4">
                <div class="bg-white p-4 p-md-5 rounded shadow-sm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <div class="mb-5">
                                <h3>Log in</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <form th:action="@{/users/login}" th:method="post">
                        <div class="row gy-3 gy-md-4 overflow-hidden">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label for="username" class="form-label">Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <input
                                        th:value="${username}"
                                        type="text"
                                        class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                        name="username"
                                        id="username"
                                        placeholder="name@example.com"
                                        required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label for="password" class="form-label">Password <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <input
                                        type="password"
                                        class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                        name="password"
                                        id="password"
                                        value=""
                                        required>
                            </div>

                            <p th:if="${bad_credentials}" class="errors alert alert-danger">
                                Invalid username or password for user: <span th:text="${username}"></span>.
                            </p>



                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="d-grid">
                                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">Log in now</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer th:replace="~{fragments/footer :: footer}"></footer>


</body>
</html>


My User Controller:
package bg.tihomir.mebelshop.web.user;

import bg.tihomir.mebelshop.service.UserService;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {


    private final UserService userService;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public UserController(UserService userService,
                          ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "auth-login";
    }

    //This should be post mapping!
    @PostMapping("/login-error")
    public String onFailedLogin(
            @RequestParam(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY) String username,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes
    ) {
        redirectAttributes
                .addFlashAttribute(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY, username)
                .addFlashAttribute("bad_credentials", true);

        return "redirect:/users/login";
    }
}

And My SecurityConfig
package bg.tihomir.mebelshop.config;

import bg.tihomir.mebelshop.repository.UserRepository;
import bg.tihomir.mebelshop.service.AppUserDetailsService;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {

        return http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                                // All static resources which are situated in js, images, css are available for anyone
                                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                                // everyone can login and register
                                .requestMatchers("/", "/users/login", "/users/register").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/living-rooms/details/{id}", "/living-rooms/all").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/kitchens/details/{id}", "/kitchens/all").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/home/about").permitAll()
                                // all other pages are available for logger in users
                                .requestMatchers("/living-rooms/add", "/living-rooms/edit").authenticated()
                                .requestMatchers("/kitchens/add","/kitchens/edit").authenticated()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(
                        formLogin -> {
                            formLogin
                                    // redirect here when we access something which is not allowed.
                                    // also this is the page where we perform login.
                                    .loginPage("/users/login")
                                    // The names of the input fields (in our case in auth-login.html)
                                    .usernameParameter(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY)
                                    .passwordParameter(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY)
                                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                                    // where to go in case that the login failed
                                    .failureForwardUrl("/users/login-error");
                        }
                ).logout(
                        logout -> {
                            logout
                                    // the URL where we should POST something in order to perform the logout
                                    .logoutUrl("/users/logout")
                                    // where to go when logged out?
                                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                                    // invalidate the HTTP session
                                    .invalidateHttpSession(true);
                        }).build();
    }


    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return new AppUserDetailsService(userRepository);
    }
}

Why the error message doesn't show up and not save  the entered email?
